# How do I expose my service to the internal docker network?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm running a group of services like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - api
  api:
    build: ./api
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
```

I want to expose the `web` service to the host's network interface, binding port 3000 on the host to port 3000 on the container. BUT, i only want to expose the `api` service to the internal network, meaning i only want it to be reachable by the web service. IIRC, that means i need to expose the `api` service to the `bridge` network in the docker-compose file.

If I was running the docker-cli, i'd do this by specifying the `--net bridge` argument. But I'm not sure how to do this in a compose file. Please help!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Docker Compose, but it looks to me like this should already do what you want - from the perspective of the `web` container, the hostname `api` should resolve to the IP address of the `api` container on the private network.

Comment: does does the docker network assign a dynamic port?

Comment: There's no need to assign ports.  If you have something listening on port `n` inside the `api` container, then the `web` container will be able to connect to it via `api:n`.

Comment: now i have a different issue, only my `api` container starts when i run `docker-compose up`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth worked. please add your answer officially and ill mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do anything special here.  Docker Compose [automatically creates a private network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you, and configures name resolution such that the `web` container will be able to hit port `x` of the `api` container at `api:x`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate internal network for the api service. And attach the api service to the internal network while attach the web service to both bridge network and internal network. You will have to update the docker-compose file with the network attaching information.

I found a version 3 example:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
  image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker
  networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  deploy:
    mode: replicated
    replicas: 6
```

Comment: There is no need to explicitly create a network here.

Answer (score 0):

**"link"** is outdated and it couples containers, you'd better define a bridge network instead(actually docker-compose does it).The following example:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    container_name: web
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
```

**conatiner_name** is the hostname in the bridge network.For the web container can access api by hostname **api**.like this:

**http://api**

btw,you'd better mount volumes in container db~

Give you one of my project as example:

// docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api-web
    working_dir: /etc/nginx/
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 2017:2017
    depends_on: 
      - server
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api-server
    working_dir: /app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 2018:2018
    depends_on: 
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    container_name: api-db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 27001:27017
```

// nginx.conf in container api-web, it connects to container api-server

```
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 1k;
gzip_buffers 16 64k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_types application/javascript text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php image/jpeg image/gif image/png;
gzip_vary on;

server {
  listen 2017;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html;
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://api-server:2018;
  }
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```